# qr code detecting from small image

Tags: blackberry, qr-code

I have integrate the zxing lib for qr code decoding in blackberry with OS 6.
  i want to know how small image can be read the QR code any possibility to read minimum small image.I have try this that it is not working for 2.5x2.5 cm image.

The device contains the 5 MP camera.

EDITED:i have check the using the default camera looking nice but in camera open by the zxing lib is not look great.so is there any way to change the quality of camera view.

Please provide me help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the size of the code, you also need to factor in how far away the code is from the camera and whether the camera supports macro-focus mode.

I would suggest using a larger code.